# Playing old low-res game causes maximized apps to fill only part of the screen

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, gaming, fullscreen

I had some maximized Google Chrome windows open. I ran StarCraft Broodwar, taking care to first open [this window as color fix](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-fix-Starcrafts-bad-colors/). The game ran fullscreen in a low resolution, as expected. Then I closed the game and the resolution of the screen returned to normal, but all (or most) maximized chrome windows had gone into the top left of the screen, while still retaining their "restore" button and borderless appearance, as though they're maximized. Any fix?

The problem doesn't seem to occur with other apps (I tried with Photoshop), just with Chrome.

Minimizing (or "restoring") and maximizing the Chrome window fixes it.

In this screenshot there's a maximized chrome window in the background, but I opened that one afterwards.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this but it never bothered me. Windows is actively switching to the game's resolution. If you disable the GPU scaling in the video driver settings, there is a high chance this will no longer occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you play Broodwars in a window instead of fullscreen, or if you can find a way to play it in a windowed borderless mode (e.g. playing it inside a VM or something of that nature), then you should avoid this behavior.